# javascript function not working in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

javascript functions on an event like onKeypress are not working , if i create a input tag through JAVSCRIPT using innerHTML . Below is the code for that i am using .
Also the same is working if i am doing it in directly JSP file .

```
$('<table id="additionalPassPopupTable'+rowNo+'" class="passenger_table_center">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td colspan="2" style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:5px; background-color:#e1e1e1;">Passenger Information</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td  style="padding-left:40px;">First Name *</td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<input type="text" name="fname" >'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<font color="red"></font>'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td  style="padding-left:40px;">Last Name *</td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<input type="text" name="lname" ></td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<font color="red"></font>'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td style="padding-left:40px;">Mobile Number</td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<input type="text" name="phoneno" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" >'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<font color="red"></font>'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
        '<td style="padding-left:40px;">Email Address</td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="100" onkeypress="return validateEmail(event)">'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<font color="red"></font>'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>').appendTo('#additionalPassengerDiv' );

function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function validateEmail(evt) {

    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (charCode < 64 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122) && (charCode != 46) && (charCode != 45) && (charCode != 95))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: where is the `test` function defined and how

Comment: make sure the function test is available in the global scope

Comment: did you try `$('#additionalPassengerDiv').html("<b>test</b>");` Okay this won't probably help you.

Comment: sorry for typo.. the function is not test . I have updated function .

Comment: You should **really** consider distilling all that HTML into a template. That's a bit of a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @user3088025: Can you share your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: check your console, is there any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello here by I am attaching your code into jsfiddle. In this your code is working. Please find fiddle here.

Thanks. [Java script function in innerhtml :JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFLH9/1/)

```
function isNumber(evt) {
alert("Validate Number");
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
 var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
}
return true;}
function validateEmail(evt) {
alert("Validate Email Id");
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (charCode < 64 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122) && (charCode != 46) && (charCode != 45) && (charCode != 95))) {
    return false;
}
return true;}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#additionalPassengerDiv' ).html('<table id="additionalPassPopupTable" class="passenger_table_center">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td colspan="2" style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:5px; background-color:#e1e1e1;">Passenger Information</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td  style="padding-left:40px;">First Name *</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<input type="text" name="fname" >'+
        '</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<font color="red"></font>'+
        '</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td  style="padding-left:40px;">Last Name *</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<input type="text" name="lname" ></td>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<font color="red"></font>'+
        '</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td style="padding-left:40px;">Mobile Number</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<input type="text" name="phoneno" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" >'+
        '</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<font color="red"></font>'+
        '</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td style="padding-left:40px;">Email Address</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="100" onkeypress="return validateEmail(event)">'+
        '</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<font color="red"></font>'+
        '</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</table>');});
```